# How can i calculate all recall accuracy precision and f1 measure for multi class classification in BERT?

Tags: nlp, classification, bert-language-model

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

def f1_score_func(preds, labels):
    preds_flat = np.argmax(preds, axis=1).flatten()
    labels_flat = labels.flatten()
    return f1_score(labels_flat, preds_flat, average='weighted')

def accuracy_per_class(preds, labels):
    label_dict_inverse = {v: k for k, v in label_dict.items()}
    
    preds_flat = np.argmax(preds, axis=1).flatten()
    labels_flat = labels.flatten()

    for label in np.unique(labels_flat):
        y_preds = preds_flat[labels_flat==label]
        y_true = labels_flat[labels_flat==label]
        print(f'Class: {label_dict_inverse[label]}')
        print(f'Accuracy: {len(y_preds[y_preds==label])}/{len(y_true)}\n')
```

Need  to calculate classification report for multi class model but it gives accuracy and f1  score only

Comment: I do not exactly understand your problem. have you tried [sklearn's classification report](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html)?

Comment: Yes  exactly also  i need to display confusion matrix

Comment: so what was the problem with sklearn's classification report? It outputs recall, precision accuracy and f-scores

Comment: It's text classification problem which contains 10 multiple class.

Comment: have you actually tried to use sklearns's classification_report? what was the output? Were there any errors? Your question is not clear and needs some clarification.

Comment: i took  refernce  from this  https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-text-classification-with-deep-learning-using-bert-b59ca2f5c613 here                                   i need  to display                                                                                                       from sklearn.metrics import classification_report print(classification_report(predictions,true_vals) this  code  output.Thank You

Comment: Please update your question with: what exactly have you tried, if there was an error, what exactly was the error etc. A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be nice

Comment: i have the above code mention in the post to calculate accuracy per class and weighted f1  score .like  that I need to calculate recall and support as well.i want to display results like classification reports like sklearn's classification report.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using the Pytorch environment. Here is the correct code to print the F1, recall and precision for each class in the dataset. If you have a trained model, load it and also the dataset to test on.

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix

val_dataset = LoadDataset('/content/val.csv')
val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val_dataset,batch_size=51) # Load the data

model.load_state_dict(torch.load('vit-base.bin')) # Load the trained model
model.cuda()                                      # For putting model on GPUs
with torch.no_grad():
 image,target = next(iter(val_loader))
 image = image.to(device)
 target = target.flatten().to(device)
 prediction = model(image)

prediction = prediction.argmax(dim=1).view(target.size()).cpu().numpy()
target = target.cpu().numpy()
print(classification_report(target,prediction,target_names=val_dataset.LE.classes_)) # LE is the label encoder
```